# How do I define the clicked element as being $(this)?

Tags: jquery

I want to add the `active` class only to the `.element` that gets a click.

The problem is, if I have many elements with the `element` class, all of them will get the `active` class.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.element').length) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

It doesn't work, for the reason that `$(this)` is not defined.

How do I define that the clicked `'.element'` is `$(this)`?

Comment: Fix the location where you add the event listener, or use what you already have in your script: `$(event.target).closest('.element').length`

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the listener as

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.element', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

What this does is sets a single listener on the document which listens for a mousedown event to bubble up the dom. If, and only if, the event is on a thing with a class including 'element' then the function will fire. Inside the function the $(this) is the '.element' thing so you can ignore any further proximity testing.  You could set the listener on the '.element' thing, I just delegated it to document as a general practice for keeping the number of listeners down.

And if you want to remove the active class from the current '.element' that was clicked then modify to

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.element', function(event) {
    $('.element.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Try it below.

```js
    $(document).on('mousedown', '.element', function(event) {
        $('.element.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
```

```css
.active 
{ background-color: cyan;
}
.element {
color: magenta;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='element'>Click me!</p>
<p class='element'>Click me!</p>
<p class='element'>Click me!</p>
<p class='element'>Click me!</p>
<p class='element'>Click me!</p>
<p class='element'>Click me!</p>
<p class='element'>Click me!</p>
```